# Wired network keeps disconnecting for a few seconds at a time

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, ethernet, 21.04

Every few minutes or so the connection to the network completely drops for several seconds. I can see this in `nload` when there is no incoming or outgoing data for a few seconds even while running something like a Minecraft server for a constant network load. I know it is not the network because all of my other computers work fine even when this computer disconnects.

Here is the output of `lspci`:

`02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)`

I have tried installing the r8168 drivers, but those didn't seem to help, I also have tried reinstalling network manager and setting managed to true in the config but no luck.

I can see the connection and use it for a few minutes, it just disconnects for a few seconds and then reconnects like nothing happened, causing any network services to lag or time out. I am currently running Ubuntu 21.04 but this issue happened on 20.04 and 20.10 as well.

**Edit:**

**lspci -nn | grep -i ethernet**

`02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)`

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 0c
       serial: 20:12:9d:20:02:6e
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-18-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.0.240 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:fbdff000-fbdfffff memory:f8ffc000-f8ffffff
```

**ip a | grep mtu**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
```

**Logs for an instance of this happening**

```
Jun 14 21:31:16 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724276.7620] device (enp2s0): state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 14 21:31:16 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724276.7770] dhcp4 (enp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Jun 14 21:31:16 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724276.7770] dhcp4 (enp2s0): state changed bound -> done
Jun 14 21:31:16 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724276.7970] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jun 14 21:31:17 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724277.1803] device (enp2s0): carrier: link connected
Jun 14 21:31:17 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724277.1806] device (enp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 14 21:31:17 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724277.1815] policy: auto-activating connection 'netplan-enp2s0' (7ea6f90b-3495-3533-948a-ef0035687c34)
Jun 14 21:31:17 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724277.1821] device (enp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'netplan-enp2s0' (7ea6f90b-3495-3533-948a-ef0035687c34)
Jun 14 21:31:17 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724277.1823] device (enp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 14 21:31:17 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724277.1828] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jun 14 21:31:17 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724277.1830] device (enp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 14 21:31:17 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724277.1836] device (enp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 14 21:31:17 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724277.1840] dhcp4 (enp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun 14 21:31:19 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724279.1925] dhcp4 (enp2s0): state changed unknown -> bound, address=192.168.0.240
Jun 14 21:31:19 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724279.1943] device (enp2s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 14 21:31:19 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724279.1985] device (enp2s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 14 21:31:19 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724279.1989] device (enp2s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 14 21:31:19 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724279.1996] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jun 14 21:31:19 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724279.2017] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jun 14 21:31:19 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724279.2019] policy: set 'netplan-enp2s0' (enp2s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jun 14 21:31:19 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724279.2023] policy: set 'netplan-enp2s0' (enp2s0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
Jun 14 21:31:19 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724279.2031] device (enp2s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jun 14 21:31:19 server NetworkManager[810]: <info>  [1623724279.2041] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
```

Seems like "carrier changed" is causing this, I will look into that.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1345932/edit) and show me `lspci -nn | grep -i ethernet` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: I’ve seen this when a machine is connected to a network with a mismatched MTU value. Could you [edit] your question to include the output of `ip a | grep mtu`?

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Thanks everyone in advance, I added the commands to the question. Thanks @waltinator for the idea to look at logs, I'm relatively new to linux so I didn't know that existed

Comment: @Waltinator does that filter the NetworkManager entries from syslog?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was my ethernet cable. I'm not sure why but it was causing these disconnects, I swapped it out for a new cat6 cable and I haven't experienced any of the lag/disconnections since.